# SQL queries from Access DB in Qlik Sense?

Tags: qliksense

At work we are currently creating reports from an Access DB using a massive number of SQL queries. We are now moving the reports to Qlik Sense. Is there an easy way to use those queries from Access on Qlik Sense while creating reports? The Queries are filtering and connecting data from multiple tables.

What I am looking for (in best case) would be an editor in my Qlik Sense Sheet where I can simply copy and paste the queries from Access SQL View into my Qlik Sense App and then creating charts from the filtered data. Not sure if that is even possible as I am completely new to Qlik Sense.

Answer (score 1):

From how Qlik Sense works, you do not copy and paste data directly into the sheets, then print the reports. You need to connect Qlik Sense to the data, though whatever method you want. This can be a database on a server, local files, AWS, etc.

Because you have SQL queries already, your best bet is going to be the data loading script, as opposed to GUI data manger. In a similar way "Arduino code" is C++ with a library of functions, the Qlik Sense data load script is SQL-like in syntax with slight modifications and additional functionality.

Get started with the loading script here: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/introduction-data-modeling.htm

Once you connect Qlik Sense to your database, you would then create the charts and graphs that you would want on your report. Whenever new data comes in, you just simply run that data load script and your graphs and charts will change according.